# Can sed be used to generate a load file for my date lookup fact table?

Tags: sed, sql

I have an SQL fact table which is used for looking up a date and returning another date.

The table schema is as follows:

```
TABLE date_lookup
   (
pk_date DATE,
plus1_months DATE,
plus2_months DATE,
plus3_months DATE
   );

UNIQUE INDEX on date_lookup(pk_date);
```

I have a load file (pipe delimited) containing dates from 01-28-2012 to 03-31-2014.

The following is an example of the load file:

```
01-28-2012|02-28-2012|03-28-2012|04-28-2012|

01-29-2012|02-29-2012|03-29-2012|04-29-2012|

01-30-2012|02-29-2012|03-30-2012|04-30-2012|

01-31-2012|02-29-2012|03-31-2012|04-30-2012|

...

03-31-2014|04-30-2014|05-31-2014|06-30-2014|
```

The rules for this fact table are:

```
IF pk_date has more than 28 days in its month
AND plus1, plus2 or plus3_months only has 28, 29 or 30 days
THEN let plus1, plus2 or plus3 equal the last day of the following month.
```

My question is: Is it possible to use `sed` to generate more dates past 03-31-2014 following the above rules for my load file, or should I write a program to accomplish this?

Comment: most sqls have a `dateadd(), datediff()` and similar functions that make this very easy to compute. It may be  possible to do this in sed, but would be torture to create and a fireable offence at most organization to check it in as code that someone else may have to maintain ;-)! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that `sed` is the right tool for the job, in this case. I think you probably want to use `awk`, if you're already familiar with `awk`, otherwise, write a program.

I've known an engineer who used `sed` and `awk` to create MSC/NASTRAN input files, which had even stricter requirements than what you mention, but he was quite familiar with the tools, so cryptic and uninformative error messages from `awk`  didn't bother him.

If you want to do this with `awk`, my advice would be to pre-process the input to remove '-' and '|' characters.  Write the `awk` program in a separate file. Use text-field positions ($1, $2, $3...), and write SQL INSERT statements for the output. It will take several attempts, so automate as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

While it is technically possible to do date arithmetic in sed, it is not at all the right tool for the job. Use a tool like awk or perl which has integer arithmetic built in.

Your requirement is an unusual one for date manipulations, so you'll need a rich date manipulation library if you don't want to hard-code the date arithmetic. Perl's [`Date::Manip`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3A%3AManip) has functions like `Date_DaysInMonth`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Manip;
use List::Util qw(/./);
sub shift_month {
    my ($delta, $y, $m, $d) = @_;
    $m += $delta;
    $y += $m / 12;
    $m %= 12;
    return ($y, $m, min($d, Date_DaysInMonth($m, $y)));
}
my $next_day = ParseDateDelta("1 day");
my ($cur, $end) = (ParseDate($ARGV[0]), ParseDate($ARGV[1]));
while (Date_Cmp($cur, $end) < 0) {
    my @ymd = UnixDate($cur, qw(%Y %m %d));
    foreach my $i (0..3) {
        printf "%02d-%04d-%02d|", @{[shift_month($i, @ymd)]}[1, 0, 2];
    }
    $cur = DateCalc($cur, $next_day);
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: I found out that the best solution is to do it with Informix SQL's date() function. see answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497714/what-is-the-best-way-to-populate-a-load-file-for-a-date-lookup-fact-table#comment15239682_11497714)